# Filter data from list of JSON string

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

I have a list of json string like this

```
{}
{"RuleId":"20cf47c5-3674-4a39-8553-00348f860fe7"}
{}
{"RuleId":"3047c5-3674-4a39-7753-003477860fe7"}
{}
{"RuleId":"20cf47c5-3674-4a39-8553-00348f860fe7"}
{"RuleId":"55cf47c5-3674-4a39-8553-00366f860hh7"}
```

now I want to get the count of element that match a rule id. How to do that with linq

Comment: Just to confirm, there are no outer brackets `[` and `]`?

Comment: no it is a C# list and those data are list elements

Comment: Just `list.Count(x => x.IndexOf(ruleId, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1)` would work :D Just kidding, please don't...but it would work in 100% of valid cases according to your description.

Comment: What do you mean by 'match a rule id'? Do you mean you want the count of elements that has a specific value for the `RuleId` property?

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

```
 string pattern = @"<a regular expression pattern>";
 Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
 var num = jsonList.Count(x => rgx.Matches(JObject.Parse(x)["RuleId"]).Count > 0);
```

Or in a simple case:

```
string specifiedId = "<Id>";
var num = jsonList.Count(x => JObject.Parse(x)["RuleId"] == specifiedId);
```

Comment: Doesn't compile, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/zaosPL.  Even if I cast the return of `JObject.Parse(x)["RuleId"]` to a `string` the `Regex` version throws an exception, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/lFrB19

Answer (score 0):

This is what I understand from your question: count a given id in elements of a list.

```
var ruleId = "20cf47c5-3674-4a39-8553-00348f860fe7";

var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("RuleId", "20cf47c5-3674-4a39-8553-00348f860fe7"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("RuleId", "3047c5-3674-4a39-7753-003477860fe7"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("RuleId", "20cf47c5-3674-4a39-8553-00348f860fe7"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("RuleId", "55cf47c5-3674-4a39-8553-00366f860hh7")
};

var count = list.Count(x => x.Value == ruleId);
```